# Does linkedin API support chat bots?

Tags: bots, linkedin-api, chatbot

We need chat bots auto-reply to my connects in Linkedin.

Does Linkedin API support any chat bots?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible and it's forbidden by the [User Agreement](https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement#rights).

> **8.2. Don’ts**
>
> > [...]
> >
> > m. Use bots or other automated methods to access the Services, add or download contacts, send or redirect messages;